# How the Environment tag E works in .htaccess mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, environment-variables

I have the following rules in a htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule mytest.php test.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !done
RewriteRule (.*)  $1?done [E=TEST:itworks]
```

The file test.php is simply

```
<?php
echo "TEST = " . getenv('TEST'); 
?>
```

When I enter the request uri test.php, the environment variable TEST is defined and it echoes 'Test = itworks'. However, when I enter the request uri mytest.php, it also goes to test.php, but the environment variable TEST is not defined and it echoes 'Test =' .

Is that the expected behavior?  If it is a bug in my environment, never mind. Otherwise, perhaps one could use that simple case to explain to me how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go through `mytest.php`, there is an additional round through mod_rewrite.

The environment variables are then prefixed with `REDIRECT_`. If you check for `REDIRECT_TEST`, you will see the desired output

```
<?php
echo "TEST = " . getenv('TEST') . "/" . getenv('REDIRECT_TEST');
```

See [Available Variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/custom-error.html#variables) for some details.

Comment: Please could someone explain this "additional round"? Why? How does the second RewriteRule know that the first fired before it so trigger the additional round? Is the additional round through the whole .htaccess file or just the last RewriteRule. I'm missing something really fundamental.

Comment: There's a technical document about how Apache [processes the rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset). You can see in the image, how an internal rewrite will be fed back to Apache for a second round or even third round until the URI isn't changed by the rules.