# Internal htaccess redirects based on combination of request and cookie not firing

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

Hi I'm struggling to achieve two things with .htaccess, presumably the same issue on each.

I am successfully setting a cookie called `site-version` to `au` or `us`.

If the cookie is set, I want http://www.example.com and http://www.example.com/ to redirect (internally) to http://www.example.com/home-au.html (if the cookie site-version=au). I also want to set an environment variable SITE_VERSION=au.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} site-version=(au|us) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /home-%1.html [NC,QSA,E=SITE_VERSION:%1]
```

The problem appears to be the regex on the RewriteRule. If I set this to `.*`, once it gives up looping it appears to set the environment variable successfully, although still not rewrite the request.

If the URL is http://www.example.com/a-specific-page.html or http://www.example.com/another-specific-page.html and the cookie is set, I want to redirect to http://www.example.com/a-specific-page-au.html or http://www.example.com/another-specific-page-au.html , ie, append the `-au` to the filename. (And set the environment variable.)

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(a-specific-page|another-specific-page)\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} site-version=au [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1-au.html [QSA,E=SITE_VERSION:au]
```

Later in htaccess I translate these URLs again so I don't want the L flag, however I also tried:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?q=$1-au.html [QSA,E=SITE_VERSION:au,L]
```

I have tried many minor variations on these themes, none trigger the rewrite.

EDIT: I've spotted a fundamental gap in my understanding. [URL rewrites trigger another loop](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset) through .htaccess, so I need to present the whole file rather than fragments, which explains why the solution works but I'm still not getting environment variables.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


########## Set the cookie if the user selects a new country #############
#  The webpage submits the existing URL plus the site-version URL parameter.   #
#  The below strips the parameter and returns to the same URL with a cookie site-version. #
#  Unless the site-version is uk (default) in which case the cookie is deleted. #

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*site-version=(au|us|za|eu)$
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [co=site-version:%1:example.com:1051200:/,R,E=SITE_VERSION:%1,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*site-version=uk$
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [co=site-version:uk:example.com:-1:/,R,E=SITE_VERSION:uk,L]

#####################
# If the cookie is present and the URL is either a-page.html or another-page.html append -au eg, a-page-au.html #

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} site-version=au [NC]
RewriteRule ^(a-page|another-page)\.html$ index.php?q=$1-au.html [NC,QSA,E=SITE_VERSION:au,L]

##########################
# Normal Friendly URLs rewrite, ie, cookie not detected or it isn't one of the listed URLs #

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I tested the first RewriteRule ^/?$ /home-%1.html [NC,QSA,E=SITE_VERSION:%1], internal redirect worked. But this cannot be seen on browser's address box, as not redirected with R flag.

Comment: OK thanks, was this with the cookie line too? I see the cookie in the browser, I go to the root URL, with or without the trailing `'`, and I get the non-au page. I think I misunderstand the `L` flag. I tried `RewriteRule ^/?$ /home-au.html [NC,QSA,E=SITE_VERSION:au,L]` , but the subsequent rule to `index.php?q=home-au.html` still fired (and doesn't look like the SITE_VERSION was set - I don't want to worry about that on this question but in case it is diagnostic). I thought the `L` would prevent any subsequent rewrites.

Comment: You'd better do this in a single step, directy to index.php?q=... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment, I've tested the first rules set without RewriteCond,

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /home-%1.html [NC,QSA,E=SITE_VERSION:%1]
```

I obtained this:

```
http://www.example.com/ =>     http://www.example.com/home-.html
```

The second ruleset has an visible error: %{THE_REQUEST} ^(a-specific-page|another-specific-page).html$ [NC]
you can try use %{REQUEST_URI} instead of  %{THE_REQUEST}.  %{THE_REQUEST} involves the words GET or POST, etc.

So you might try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} site-version=(au|us) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /home-%1.html [NC,QSA,E=SITE_VERSION:%1]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} site-version=au [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(a-specific-page|another-specific-page)\.html$ /$1-au.html [NC,QSA,E=SITE_VERSION:au]
```

Or set a visible Redirect by adding R flag as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} site-version=(au|us) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /home-%1.html [R,QSA,E=SITE_VERSION:%1]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} site-version=au [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(a-specific-page|another-specific-page)\.html$ /$1-au.html [R,NC,QSA,E=SITE_VERSION:au]
```

Comment: As suggested in your comment I made the rewrite direct to index.php and added the L flag. Apologies, the home-%1 rewrite was actually later in .htaccess so this shouldn't have been the problem, although I hadn't spotted that. However your tidied specific-page Rewrite seems to have cleared up whatever it was that stopped the rewrites working - silly mistake. Not getting the environment variable in PHP using $site_version = getenv('SITE_VERSION') on either Rewrite, although I'm already immensely grateful!

Comment: Worst thing in the world is to have all your dreams come true..! Solution so far - cookies and rewrites working, env vars gone. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} site-version=au [NC]` `RewriteRule ^(a-specific-page|another-specific-page)\.html$ index.php?q=$1-au.html [NC,QSA,E=SITE_VERSION:au,L]` `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} site-version=(au|us) [NC]` `RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?q=home-%1.html [NC,QSA,E=SITE_VERSION:%1,L]`

PS. I'm fairly confident of my php as I saw it working.

Comment: Got it working with a non-L rule up top specifically for the environment variable, ie, `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} site-version=(au|us) [NC]` `RewriteRule .* - [NC,E=SITE_VERSION:%1]` I needed this anyway as I want the cookie in SITE_VERSION regardless of whether I'm on a-specific-page etc.

Comment: This is in addition to (and above) the other rewrites. SITE_VERSION didn't seem to be set otherwise. The reason for this is that just a few pages are fully localized, the rest just need a different phone number, email address and pre-selected localization drop-down on them.

Comment: In case anyone else is doing something similar, the drop-down for setting the country calls the current URL `document.location.pathname + '?site-version=us'`. The param is removed by htaccess in a R rewrite, and a cookie put in the header. My cookie-setting lines: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*site-version=(au|us|za|eu)$` `RewriteRule (.*) $1? [co=site-version:%1:example.com:1051200:/,R,E=SITE_VERSION:%1,L]` If UK is selected (the default) the cookie is deleted `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*site-version=uk$` `RewriteRule (.*) $1? [co=site-version:uk:example.com:-1:/,R,E=SITE_VERSION:uk,L]`

Comment: Rolled this out to production, an Apache 2.4 server (mine's Apache 2.2) and the environment variable disappeared again. There are several fundamental htaccess aspects I haven't picked up in three days trawling Apache docs, tutorials, etc. One - when you rewrite "there is an additional round through mod-rewrite". I have no idea what this means, I suspect it is related to my problem as I thought htaccess is iterated through once unless `R` is specified (although I don't get REDIRECT_SITE_VERSION). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205194/how-the-environment-tag-e-works-in-htaccess-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

The full solution. This does the following:

1. Detects the URL parameter ?site-version, and if found, sets a cookie on the client called site-version, storing the country code (au, eu, za, etc), to last 2 years (1051200 minutes). It then removes the parameter from the URL and gets the user's browser to request the original URL again.
2. Except, if site-version=uk, this is the default setting for the website, so the cookie is deleted (see the -1 in the `co` flag).

Specific pages have local versions written of them. They are accessed by adding the country code to the URL. So the Australian version of costs.html is costs-au.html.

1. If the cookie is detected, which might be on a repeat visit, or it might be due to the redirect in step 1 above, the URL is examined. If the URL is one of the pages that has a local version, the country code is added to the URL. The URL is then passed to index.php - the common way to have pleasant-looking, search engine-friendly URLs. The rewriting of the URL triggers another iteration through .htaccess. (Nb. As far as I'm aware, the E= flags on these rules don't achieve anything as when .htaccess is reiterated through the environment variable is lost. E= flags are effectively invalid if the URL is changed, as they achieve nothing.)
2. If the cookie is detected, the value is stored in an environment variable called HTTP_SITE_VERSION. (Environment variables should always be prefixed with `HTTP_`, because servers running suexec ignore variables that don't start with `HTTP_`. suexec is an Apache feature that allows scripts to be run by a user other than the user running the Apache process, so is probably common among shared hosts.)
3. My PHP serves the altered URL, ie, costs-au.html, unaware that it has been changed. (FYI the browser URL is costs.html as this was an internal redirect.)
4. For all pages, regardless of whether they are in the list and have translations, the environment variable is set. PHP detects this with $site_version = getenv('HTTP_SITE_VERSION') (which returns false for UK as the cookie and variable aren't set and getenv returns false for missing vars) and displays the appropriate nuggets such as phone number or address.

So, the final, working solution is this (fix details below):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

########## Set the cookie if the user selects a new country #############
#  The webpage submits the existing URL plus the site-version URL parameter.   #
#  The below strips the parameter and returns to the same URL with a cookie site-version. #
#  Unless the site-version is uk (default) in which case the cookie is deleted. #

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*site-version=(au|us|za|eu)$
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [co=site-version:%1:example.com:1051200:/,R,E=HTTP_SITE_VERSION:%1,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*site-version=uk$
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [co=site-version:uk:example.com:-1:/,R,E=HTTP_SITE_VERSION:uk,L]

#############################
# Once the URLs have been rewritten, htaccess is iterated through again - re-iterating loses the environment variable to re-set it here

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} site-version=(au|us|eu|za|uk) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [NC,E=HTTP_SITE_VERSION:%1]

#####################
# If the cookie is present and the URL is either a-page.html or another-page.html append -au eg, a-page-au.html #

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} site-version=au [NC]
RewriteRule ^(a-page|another-page)\.html$ index.php?q=$1-au.html [NC,QSA,E=HTTP_SITE_VERSION:au,L]


##########################
# Normal Friendly URLs rewrite, ie, cookie not detected or it isn't one of the listed URLs #

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The fixes I needed: The two changes suggested by jacouh:

1. Put the string I want to match into the RewriteRule line instead of a RewriteCond. Silly oversight of mine.
2. Don't change the URL in two steps, go straight to index.php?q=.. rather than via the new URL, and add the `L` flag. If the URL is changed by any rule, the whole htaccess is re-iterated through. Doing everything in one step makes things much simpler.

But this was incomplete. When the URL was rewritten, a new iteration through .htaccess was triggered. This deletes all environment variables and prefixes headers with REDIRECT_.

So I also needed to add the setting of the environment variable in an iteration of .htaccess with no rewrites triggering. (When the htaccess file is iterated through again, which happens if any rule changes the URL, the environment variables disappear. Sorry to be verbose but this is confusing.) So I need an iteration of htaccess which does not change the URL in which to set the environment variable. Hence needing to add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} site-version=(au|us|eu|za|uk) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [NC,E=HTTP_SITE_VERSION:%1]
```

This sets the environment variable on the iteration after the URL has been rewritten. Hey presto, worked on my server.

But when I rolled it out, even though the rewrites were happening, the variable disappeared again.

It turns out that on servers running suexec to protect PHP, environment variables need to be prefixed with `HTTP_`.